# MongoDB server on Ubuntu, doesn't send acknowledgment on insert

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

using Ubuntu as mongodb server (mongo version 3.0.4, Ubuntu - 14). Some of the inserts never return acknowledgment. What could be the reason for that, and how can it be fixed? The document is written to db collection.
Happens on ~1/10,000 documents.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides different levels of write concern to better address the specific needs of applications. Clients may adjust write concern to ensure that the most important operations persist successfully to an entire MongoDB deployment.

For other less critical operations, clients can adjust the write concern to ensure faster performance rather than ensure persistence to the entire deployment.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/

If you want ensure receive acknowledgment on insert you can put **w** param **> 1** or "**majority**" (enough in most cases).

**IMPORTANT: If you set w to a number that is greater than the number of set members that hold data, MongoDB waits for the non-existent members to become available, which means MongoDB blocks indefinitely.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but my question refer to server side. I have access to the server and I'm trying to understand this issue.